# Assign a number to each unique value in a list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of strings. I want to assign a unique number to each string (the exact number is not important), and create a list of the same length using these numbers, in order. Below is my best attempt at it, but I am not happy for two reasons:

1. It assumes that the same values are next to each other
2. I had to start the list with a `0`, otherwise the output would be incorrect

My code:

```
names = ['ll', 'll', 'll', 'hl', 'hl', 'hl', 'LL', 'LL', 'LL', 'HL', 'HL', 'HL']
numbers = [0]
num = 0
for item in range(len(names)):
    if item == len(names) - 1:
      break
    elif names[item] == names[item+1]:
        numbers.append(num)
    else:
        num = num + 1
        numbers.append(num)
print(numbers)
```

I want to make the code more generic, so it will work with an unknown list. Any ideas?

Comment: how about sorting the list before applying algorithm

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Without using an external library (check the **EDIT** for a `Pandas` solution) you can do it as follows :

```
d = {ni: indi for indi, ni in enumerate(set(names))}
numbers = [d[ni] for ni in names]
```

Brief explanation:

In the first line, you assign a number to each unique element in your list (stored in the dictionary `d`; you can easily create it using a dictionary comprehension; `set` returns the unique elements of `names`).

Then, in the second line, you do a list comprehension and store the actual numbers in the list `numbers`.

One example to illustrate that it also works fine for unsorted lists:

```
# 'll' appears all over the place
names = ['ll', 'll', 'hl', 'hl', 'hl', 'LL', 'LL', 'll', 'LL', 'HL', 'HL', 'HL', 'll']
```

That is the output for `numbers`:

```
[1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

As you can see, the number `1` associated with `ll` appears at the correct places.

**EDIT**

If you have [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) available, you can also use [`pandas.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html#pandas-factorize) (which seems to be quite efficient for huge lists and also works fine for lists of tuples as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207926/how-to-i-factorize-a-list-of-tuples?noredirect=1&lq=1)):

```
import pandas as pd

pd.factorize(names)
```

will then return

```
(array([(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 0]),
 array(['ll', 'hl', 'LL', 'HL'], dtype=object))
```

Therefore,

```
numbers = pd.factorize(names)[0]
```

Answer (score 7):

If the condition is that the numbers are unique and *the exact number is not important*, then you can build a mapping relating each item in the list to a unique number on the fly, assigning values from a count object:

```
from itertools import count

names = ['ll', 'll', 'hl', 'hl', 'LL', 'LL', 'LL', 'HL', 'll']

d = {}
c = count()
numbers = [d.setdefault(i, next(c)) for i in names]
print(numbers)
# [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 0]
```

---

You could do away with the extra names by using [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) on the list and a count object, and setting the map function as `{}.setdefault` (see @StefanPochmann's comment):

```
from itertools import count

names = ['ll', 'll', 'hl', 'hl', 'LL', 'LL', 'LL', 'HL', 'll']
numbers  = map({}.setdefault, names, count()) # call list() on map for Py3
print(numbers)
# [0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 0]
```

---

As an extra, you could also use [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), in case you already have numpy installed:

```
import numpy as np

_, numbers = np.unique(names, return_inverse=True)
print(numbers)
# [3 3 2 2 1 1 1 0 3]
```

Comment: No need for the extra variables if you do `list(map({}.setdefault, names, count()))`.

Comment: In the first solution, you can use `len(d)` instead of `next(c)`, a la: `numbers = [d.setdefault(i, len(d)) for i in names]

Answer (score 5):

If you have `k` different values, this maps them to integers `0` to `k-1` in order of first appearance:

```
>>> names = ['b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'b']
>>> tmp = {}
>>> [tmp.setdefault(name, len(tmp)) for name in names]
[0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it more generic you can wrap it in a function, so these hard-coded values don't do any harm, because they are local.

If you use efficient lookup-containers (I'll use a plain dictionary) you can keep the first index of each string without loosing to much performance:

```
def your_function(list_of_strings):

    encountered_strings = {}
    result = []

    idx = 0
    for astring in list_of_strings:
        if astring in encountered_strings:  # check if you already seen this string
            result.append(encountered_strings[astring])
        else:
            encountered_strings[astring] = idx
            result.append(idx)
            idx += 1
    return result
```

And this will assign the indices in order (even if that's not important):

```
>>> your_function(['ll', 'll', 'll', 'hl', 'hl', 'hl', 'LL', 'LL', 'LL', 'HL', 'HL', 'HL'])
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
```

This needs only one iteration over your list of strings, which makes it possible to even process generators and similar.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to modify your script very slightly and it looks ok:

```
names = ['ll', 'hl', 'll', 'hl', 'LL', 'll', 'LL', 'HL', 'hl', 'HL', 'LL', 'HL', 'zzz']
names.sort()
print(names)
numbers = []
num = 0
for item in range(len(names)):
    if item == len(names) - 1:
      break
    elif names[item] == names[item+1]:
        numbers.append(num)
    else:
        numbers.append(num)
        num = num + 1
numbers.append(num)
print(numbers)
```

You can see it is very simmilar, only thing is that instead adding number for NEXT element i add number for CURRENT element. That's all. Oh, and sorting. It sorts capital first, then lowercase in this example, you can play with `sort(key= lambda:x ...)` if you wish to change that. (Perhaps like this: `names.sort(key = lambda x: (x.upper() if x.lower() == x else x.lower()))`
)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mapping strings to integers, that suggests using a dict. So you can do the following:

```
d = dict()

counter = 0

for name in names:
    if name in d:
        continue
    d[name] = counter
    counter += 1

numbers = [d[name] for name in names]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar [factorizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44207926/how-to-i-factorize-a-list-of-tuples/44296764#44296764) solution with `collections.defaultdict` and `itertools.count`:

```
import itertools as it
import collections as ct


names = ['ll', 'll', 'hl', 'hl', 'LL', 'LL', 'LL', 'HL', 'll']

dd = ct.defaultdict(it.count().__next__)
[dd[i] for i in names]
# [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 0]
```

Every new occurrence calls the next integer in `itertools.count` and adds new entry to `dd`.

Answer (score 0):

**Pandas**' [`factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) can simply factorize unique strings:

```py
import pandas as pd

codes, uniques = pd.factorize(names)
codes
>>> array([3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

This can also be done in **Scikit-learn** with `LabelEncoder()`:

```py
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
codes = le.fit_transform(names)
codes
>>> array([3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Try This Also:-

```
names = ['ll', 'll', 'll', 'hl', 'hl', 'hl', 'LL', 'LL', 'LL', 'HL', 'HL', 'HL']

indexList = list(set(names))

print map(lambda name:indexList.index(name),names)
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann, yes you can write this also map(indexList.index,names), if you don't need to write lambda