# Assign a different colour for each label in a plt.scatterplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am drawing this scatterplot in python, and I would like to have the dot drawn in a different (contrasting) colour for each label. Each label has multiple points.

Seems like it could be something to feed to annotate, but I am not quite sure how, as I haven't been able to find it:

```
  for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    x, y = low_dim_embs[i, :]
    plt.scatter(x, y)
    plt.annotate(label,
                 xy=(x, y),
                 xytext=(5, 2),
                 textcoords='offset points',
                 ha='right',
                 va='bottom')
```

I can replace the above command by:

```
plt.scatter(x, y, color=mycolors)
```

Which will give me manually specified colors, but for each of the entries (and there are many repetitions per entry). Is there any automatic way?

My dataset looks like this:

```
x,y,label
1,2,label1
1,3,label1
2,-1,label1
4,1,label2
5,1,label2
...
```

Each coordinate belonging to labelx should have the same colour (I would probably also need those in a legend).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to work around the issue of same labels to same colors is to write a script that generates a list of colors that assign a unique number to each unique value in your data (that line of code is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42350201/5103802)):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

line = plt.figure()

data = [[1,1.5,3,2.4,5],[2,4.1,2.4,1,3],["apple","banana","grape","apple","banana"]]    

colors = [{ni: indi for indi, ni in enumerate(set(data[2]))}[ni] for ni in data[2]]

plt.scatter(data[0], data[1], c=colors, cmap="plasma")    

for i in range(len(data[0])):    
    plt.annotate(str(data[2][i]),
                     xy=(data[0][i], data[1][i]),
                     xytext=(data[0][i], data[1][i]),
                     textcoords='offset points',
                     ha='right',
                     va='bottom')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That gives me an error:     c = tuple(map(float, c))
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable. Also, would this really make that if 10 entries have the same label they get the same colour?

Comment: @dorien No, it wouldn't meet that requirement, I wasn't aware of that before your edit, sorry. I'll try to update my answer.