# from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot equivalent in pytorch?

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network, word2vec

I just started using pytorch for NLP. I found a tutorial that uses `from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot` and converts text to one_hot representation given a vocabulary size.

For example:

The input is

```
vocab_size = 10000
sentence = ['the glass of milk',
            'the cup of tea',
            'I am a good boy']

onehot_repr = [one_hot(words, vocab_size) for words in sentence]
```

The output is"

```
[[6654, 998, 8896, 1609], [6654, 998, 1345, 879], [123, 7653, 1, 5678,7890]]
```

how can i perform the same procedure in pytorch and get the output like above.

Answer (score 1):

PyTorch fundamentally works with Tensors, and is not designed to work with strings. You can use [SK Learn's `LabelEncoder`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42350029/assign-a-number-to-each-unique-value-in-a-list/66738109#66738109) to encode your words however:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit([w for s in sentence for w in s.split()])

onehot_repr = [le.transform(s.split()) for s in sentence]
```

```
>>> [array([10,  5,  8,  7]), array([10,  4,  8,  9]), array([0, 2, 1, 6, 3])]
```